# External and Internal Firewall in Azure

Tags: azure, firewall

Can I use an Azure firewall for external (public facing) and as well as internal at once as shown in this architecture diagram :

[image: Firewalls Azure]

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need an internal Firewall or is it how it looks on-prem and what you really want is a DMZ in which you can control what traffic is allowed?
The reason for my question is that you can control traffic with Network Security Groups and therefore only need a public firewall.

Microsoft architecture

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/dmz/secure-vnet-dmz

As well as Cisco in Azure recommendation

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa95/asav/quick-start/asav-quick/asav-azure.pdf

I often encounter customers who “demands” firewalls between subnets but don’t realize that you can limit and control traffic with NSG’s.